# Use macro in match branch

Tags: rust, macros

I have a macro that abstract a variant of my enum :

```rust
struct Test(u64);

enum MyEnum {
  Variant1(Test)
}

macro_rules! MyEnumVariant {
   ["1"] => MyEnum::Variant1
}
```

I want to use in a match branch :

```rust
fn main() {
  let t = MyEnum::Variant1(Test(3));

  match t {
    MyEnumVariant!["1"](test) => println!("Value of test is: {}", test.0)
  }
}
```

This cause a compile error. I don't find any syntax that allow me to use my macro to replace the variant access in the match.

Here is a [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d8b0a144cbeec7f5cdbfec6c034f47fe) to this little example with the compile error.

Do you have a syntax to allow macros to be used here ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to produce partial patterns with a declarative macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the macro enclose the whole pattern you want to produce. This compiles:

```rust
macro_rules! MyEnumVariant {
    ["1" ( $p:pat )] => { MyEnum::Variant1($p) }
}
```

```rust
match t {
    MyEnumVariant!["1"(test)] => println!("Value of test is: {}", test.0)
}
```